# Can't get sum of dispense amount to add grouped dispenses

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get a list of people who have been into the store in the last 90 days and have had a dispense. I am trying to get a sum of the dispense amount and then group them by their full names and individual person ID. When doing this the sum of the dispense amount doesn't get added to it. See the query below.

```
select sum(d.dispense_amount), 
       p.full_name, 
       d.dispense_date, 
       p.person_id, 
       p.gender
from   dispense d,
       patients p
where  d.pid = p.pid
and    d.dispense_date >= sysdate -90
group by dispense_amount, p.person_id, p.full_name, d.dispense_date, p.gender;
```

The sum of the dispenses are not adding when doing this. I have attempted to split the query to show like this:

```
select sum(dispense_amount) from dispense
where  pid = 34359820391
and    dispense_date >= sysdate -90;
```

And the person here has the correct amount. When inputting the pid into the above query you get a different value.

Could someone advise?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Hi I'm using SQL developer, and Oracle 11.2.0

Comment: Do you have multiple records with the same `pid` in the `patients` table?  Also, is `patients.pid` different to `patients.person_id` (it may be, but I'd have guessed that pid stood for person id; but maybe it's patient id and I'm wrong)?  Also, you're including `dispense_date` in your group by field; so you'll get a record per patient per date... that's different to your second query where you're not grouping by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Then, I think you want:

```
select sum(d.dispense_amount), 
       p.full_name, p.person_id, p.gender
from patients p join
     dispense d
     on d.pid = p.pid
where d.dispense_date >= sysdate - 90
group by p.person_id, p.full_name, p.gender;
```

Do not include the `dispense_date` or `dispense_amount` in the `group by`.  You only seem to want one row per person.

Comment: Why should we never use the commas in the from clause ?

Comment: Because it is *the best practice*. You'd rather use ANSI join, it comes handy especially when there are outer joins. Some people have difficulties in understanding Oracle's "(+)" syntax which shows outer join. Besides, using it, you can't outer join the same table to more than a single other table, so - get used to ANSI join.